# cant drag files or folders anywhere in freya

Tags: files

I may be missing something or just inexperienced but I cant find a way to drag files or folders in elementary. im used to windows and ubuntu 14.04 (both of which make this easy) I like the clean interface of elementary but this is frustrating

Answer (score 3):

Hold the right-click button and drag using the trackpad.

If you hold the right-click button too long before dragging, then the contextual menu opens up instead.

Comment: is this by design?